# Azure Data Factory Integration runtimes will not start

Tags: azure, dataflow, azure-data-factory

I have an issue where Azure Data Factory Integration runtimes will not start.

When I trigger the pipeline I get the following error in Monitor -> Pipeline runs "InternalServerError executing request"

[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FoulU.png)

In "view activity run" I can see that it's the Data Flow that failed with the error

```
{
    "errorCode": "1006",
    "message": "Hit unexpected exception and execution failed.",
    "failureType": "SystemError",
    "target": "data_wrangling_ks",
    "details": []
}
```

[Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ctZC2.png)

(the two successful runs are from a Self-Hosted IR)

When i try to start "Data flow debug" it will just disappear without any information.

This issue started earlier today without any changes in Data Factory config or the pipeline.

Please help and thank you for your time.

---

SOLVED:
I changed the *Compute type* from **General Purpose** to **Compute Optimized** and that solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

By looking at the error message, it seems like this issue has occurred due ADF related service outage in West Europe region. The issue has been resolved by the product team. Please open a MSDN thread if you ever encounter this issue.

Ref: *[Azure Data Factory Pipeline failed while running data flows with error message : Hit unexpected exception and execution failed](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/662f53db-0a7c-492f-a094-52ea2e59397a/azure-data-factory-pipeline-failed-while-running-data-flows-with-error-message-hit-unexpected?forum=AzureDataFactory)*